# How can I write and read custom data from express-session using typescript?

Tags: node.js, session, express, typescript, types

I'm trying insert my data (like login or id) into a session.
But when I'm writing `req.session.login`, typescript returns error: 
"Object is possibly 'undefined'." I was trying everything and I was looking for answer in google, but I didn't found anything.

Here is my `'src/app.ts'` included into simple start file `'bin/www.js'`.

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as session from 'express-session';
import * as cookieParser from "cookie-parser";

let app:express.Application = express();

app.use(cookieParser("sssh!"));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'sssssh! That\'s the secret',
    name: 'session',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      path: '*',
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000,
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + (3 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
    }
}));
app.use("/test", (req:express.Request, res:express.Response, next:express.NextFunction)=>{
      let ses = req.session;
      // Here I want to do something similar to cookies, 
      //like req.session.login = "login" or ses.login = "login"
      res.cookie('name', "lastname");
      console.log(req.cookies);
      res.send(req.session);
});
```

If I'm not wrong, this declaration (`req.session.login = "login"`) should work in normal javascript file.
I'm sure that I missed something important here.

Comment: Any word on this? This is a critical bug.